# Does a ComponentRef.destroy() method also unsubscribe the Components Event Emitters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

If we have a dynamic (Created dynamically - not declaratively) `ComponentRef` instance, and we call `destroy()` on the instance, will that unsubcribe any subscriptions to `EventEmitter` instances that are subscribed to.

For example if we an `output` `EventEmitter` and we subscribe to it like this:

```
this.componentRef.instance.output.subscribe(event => console.log(event));
```

And we call `componentRef.destroy()` will that take care of unsubscribing the subscription to the `output` `EventEmitter`?

### Summary Article Incorporating Answers

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/subscribing-to-dynamic-component-eventemitters-4f931a5013e3

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/cleaning-up-subscriptions-to-dynamic-component-event-emitters-ad08c838c7a8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subscribe method is called there is a subscription object returned. If I keep track of that object. You have to can call unsubscribe whenever Angular is destroying the component.

E.x:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

It will not unsubscribe from `ngOnDestroy()`

Answer (score 1):

There's a `onDestroy` callback from componentRef that you can hook to clean up the subscriptions

```
  /**
   * A lifecycle hook that provides additional developer-defined cleanup
   * functionality for the component.
   * @param callback A handler function that cleans up developer-defined data
   * associated with this component. Called when the `destroy()` method is invoked.
   */
  abstract onDestroy(callback: Function): void;
```

> example

```
const sub=this.componentRef.instance.output.subscribe(event => console.log(event));
this.componentRef.onDestroy(()=>{
    sub.unsubscribe()
})
```

Comment: A demo would be nice to see.

Comment: It works!  Nice!  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-hola-hw2jpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/subscribing-to-dynamic-component-eventemitters-4f931a5013e3

Comment: nice follow up blogging .

Comment: Thanks - And great tip! - It makes creating many dynamic components with simple cleanup very easy.

Comment: You can also check what object is passed by the callback, so u don’t have to rely on local variable

Comment: An example would be great?

Comment: Also did another writeup on the callback specifically: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/cleaning-up-subscriptions-to-dynamic-component-event-emitters-ad08c838c7a8